# Extract first date from string in a data frame

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I want to extract the first date in format yyyy-mm-dd from a dataframe (Pandas). When no date is found, just return an empty string.
These are some example of the data stored in the dataframe.

```
1976-05-17 [ ]
[ ] 1976-05-172 
1976-05-17       
1976-05-17 Atlanta, Georgia U.S.  
1976-05-17 1975-07-11
( 1976-05-17 ) 1976-05-17 (age 38) [ ]
```

In all cases I want **1976-05-17** or an empty string.

The result would be running a regular expression on a DataFrame and add the result to a new column

Comment: what do you mean by the first date? What should the output be? It would also help if you provided a dataframe sample with expected output, the regex is simple `"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}"`

Comment: With **first date** I mean that if the string is **1976-05-17 1985-07-11**, it should return only **1976-05-17**

Comment: Yep, but are you applying it to a certain column of your df, in the end will you have a column with either just a single date or an empty string?

Comment: Correct, single date or empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the first use `search` which will stop at the first matched substring:

```
 r = re.compile("\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}")
```

Using your sample:

```
lines = """1976-05-17 [ ]
[ ] 1976-05-172
1976-05-17
1976-05-17 Atlanta, Georgia U.S.
1976-05-17 1975-07-11
( 1976-05-17 ) 1976-05-17 (age 38) [ ]"""
r = re.compile("\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}")
for line in lines.splitlines():
    m = r.search(line)
    if m:
        print(m.group())
```

Output:

```
1976-05-17
1976-05-17
1976-05-17
1976-05-17
1976-05-17
1976-05-17
```

If you are applying it to a df, you can test if there is a match if so use the match or else use an empty string as the value i.e.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.txt")
print(df)
def match(x):
    m = r.search(x)
    if m:
        return  m.group()
    return  ""
```

Output:

```
print(df)
print df["date"].apply(match)

                                     date
0                          1976-05-17 [ ]
1                         [ ] 1976-05-172
2                              1976-05-17
3        1976-05-17 Atlanta, Georgia U.S.
4                   1976-05-17 1975-07-11
5  ( 1976-05-17 ) 1976-05-17 (age 38) [ ]


0    1976-05-17
1    1976-05-17
2    1976-05-17
3    1976-05-17
4    1976-05-17
5    1976-05-17
Name: date, dtype: object
```

You could also set the column equal to the return value of `str.extract` if you were ok with Nan for non matches:

```
print df["date"].str.extract(r"(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})")
```

Adding `"foo"` to the column:

```
0    1976-05-17
1    1976-05-17
2    1976-05-17
3    1976-05-17
4    1976-05-17
5    1976-05-17
6           NaN
Name: date, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to find dates in a string:

```
import re

line = '1976-05-17 Atlanta, Georgia U.S.'
dates = re.findall('[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}', line)

date = dates[0] if len(dates) else None
```

Comment: If there are 2 dates, it returns both, right? I need only the first one.