# Pandas: Change dates in dataframe to same date format

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains a column which holds:

```
Date:
31MAR2005
30-06-05
311205
```

I would like to convert these dates to the format : 30-06-05 (DD-MM-JJ). What is the simplest way to do this? The fields are not in a date format yet, only strings.

Comment: Are these the three types of patterns for the strings? Or are there even more patterns (perhaps some you aren't even aware of?)? Secondly, if there are common patterns, do you know the rows where these patterns will appear?

Comment: @measureallthethings, these three are the only patterns that exist in this column. I do not know the specific rows in which those occur..

Comment: If those are the only 3 patters I would suggest creating a function using some string recognition and strptime and then applying it to your dataframe.

Comment: @Alex sounds helpful, but can you give me a code example?

Comment: Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801019/extract-first-date-from-string-in-a-data-frame
This is slightly different in that it is searching for one particular pattern in the function `match()`, but if you add some logic to search for the three patterns shown here it should work for your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Pandas' vectorize string methods](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#text-string-methods) to extract the day, month and year from each date string:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['31MAR2005', '30-06-05', '311205'], columns=['Date'])
tmp = df['Date'].str.extract(r'(\d{2})-?(\D{3}|\d{2})-?.*(\d{2})')
tmp.columns = ['day', 'month', 'year']
```

yields

```
In [228]: tmp
Out[228]: 
  day month year
0  31   MAR   05
1  30    06   05
2  31    12   05
```

Now you can change 3-letter month abbreviations to numeric strings by calling `Series.map`:

```
import calendar
monthmap = {calendar.month_abbr[i].upper(): '{:02d}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 13)}
monthmap.update({'{:02d}'.format(i):'{:02d}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 13)})
tmp['month'] = tmp['month'].map(monthmap)
```

yields

```
In [230]: tmp
Out[230]: 
  day month year
0  31    03   05
1  30    06   05
2  31    12   05
```

And finally, you can re-assign `df['Date']` to the desired date-string format:

```
df['Date'] = tmp['day']+'-'+tmp['month']+'-'+tmp['year']
```

yields

```
In [232]: df
Out[232]: 
       Date
0  31-03-05
1  30-06-05
2  31-12-05
```

Especially if the DataFrame is long,
using vectorized string methods should be faster than using `df.apply` to call a Python function once for every row value.

Also note that this accomplishes the task without parsing the strings as
Timestamps. That might be a good or a bad thing.
On the one hand, it may improve performance. On
the other hand, it may allow invalid date strings (such as `'30FEB2005'`) to slip through.

After re-formatting the strings, you could call

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

to convert the date strings into proper `Timestamps`. Then invalid date strings would become `NaT` (Not-a-Timestamp) values.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my example :

```
def string_to_date(my_string):
    if '-' in my_string:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(my_string, '%d-%m-%y')
    elif my_string.isdigit():
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(my_string, '%d%m%y')
    elif my_string.isalnum():
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(my_string, '%d%b%Y')
```

now I'm testing it on your dataframe df :

```
In[116]: df['Date:'].apply(lambda x: string_to_date(x))
Out[114]: 
0   2005-03-31
1   2005-06-30
2   2005-12-31
Name: Date:, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```