# Converting to date format in pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains a column which holds:

```
Date:
31062005
072005
12005
2012
```

I would like to convert these dates to the format:

```
Date:
31/06/2005
07/2005
01/2005
2012
```

What is the simplest way to do this? The fields are not in a date format yet, only strings.

Comment: Is that a real column, or is it a made up one? What you're asking requires a very simple but convoluted method. What have you done till now to address your question?

Comment: I tried this solution [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32829038/6685708) but in this case there are missing dates and months where I have a problem formulating the correct regex.

Comment: Yes, that is because the answer in the link has all three parts, Date, Month and Year. In your case, they are not consistent. But they all have `'/'`, so maybe I have an idea. I'll try it and post an answer...

Comment: @Kartik My dataset has a million rows and this is just a example of the Date column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose you write a function

```
def convert_date(s):
    if len(s) == 4:
        return s
    elif len(s) < 7:
        return s[: -4].zfill(2) + '/' + s[-4: ]
    else:
        return s[: -6].zfill(2) + '/' + s[-6: -4].zfill(2) + '/' + s[-4]
```

Then if your dates are in `df.dates`, you can use

```
>>> df.dates.apply(convert_date)                                   
0    31/06/2
1    07/2005
2    01/2005
3       2012
Name: dates, dtype: object
```

Note that this converts a string in one form to a string in a different form, meaning you can't really manipulate dates further. If you want to do that, I'd suggest you amend the preceding function to use the appropriate `datetime.datetime.strptime` for the format matching the length of the string. It could look something like this:

```
def convert_date(s):
    if len(s) == 4:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime('%Y')
    elif len(s) < 8:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime('%m%Y')
    else:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime('%d%m%Y')
```

Note that your first date (with the 31 days) seems illegal, though.

Comment: Thanks a ton. A small change in elif structure made it perfect. 'def convert_date(s):
    if len(s) == 4:
        return s
    elif len(s) < 7:
        return s[: -4].zfill(2) + '/' + s[-4: ]
    else:
        return s[: -6].zfill(2) + '/' + s[-6: -4].zfill(2) + '/' + s[-4:]'

Comment: Thanks, @rpkar - updated. Since you seem new to the site, note that you can upvote all answers (more than one) you find helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['30/06/2005', '07/2005', '1/2005', '2012'], columns=['Date'])

temp = pd.DataFrame(df['Date'].str.split('/').apply(reversed).tolist())\
    .fillna('01')
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(temp[0].str.cat(temp[1].str.zfill(2))\
                            .str.cat(temp[2].str.zfill(2)), format='%Y%m%d')
```